# Java Spring, waiting for AsyncHandlers

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

apologies for the basic question; I'm new to the Java world and the spring framework. I've built a little example application that makes a bunch of async requests to an external service and returns a list of the responses ('metrics'), but I need to make my application wait until all the responses have come back. Right now I have a (don't hate me) Thread.sleep while I let the results come back, but obviously this is very nasty. Can anyone suggest a better way of architecting this?

Calling class:

```
@Service
public class MetricService {

@Autowired
private MetricProcessor processor;

private LinkedBlockingQueue<Metric> queue;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
public void queryExternalService() {
   List<Metrics> metrics = new ArrayList<>();
   metrics = processor.getMetrics();

   //this is horrible and I'm a horrible human being
   try {
      Thread.sleep(10000); //wait for the requests to come back
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   queue.addAll(metrics);
}
}
```

Class:

```
@Component
public class MetricProcessor {

@Autowired
private AsyncClient externalClient;

public List<Metrics> getMetrics() {
   List<Metrics> returnObj = new Arraylist<>();

   for(Blah blah : bleh) {
      Request request = new Request("abc");
      externalClient.getMetricAsync(request, new AsyncHandler<request, result>() {
         @Override
         public void onError(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
         }

         @Override
         public void onSuccess(Request request, Result result) {
            returnObj.add(new Metric(result.getKey(), result.getValue()));
         }
      });
   }
   return returnObj;
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try a `Future`.

In `MetricService`:

```
public void queryExternalService() {
    Future<List<Metrics>> metricsFuture = processor.getMetrics();
    try {
        queue.addAll(metricsFuture.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So notice instead of the desired `List`, your processor provides a reference to a `Future` which may fulfil that request later:

```
public Future<List<Metrics>> getMetrics() {
    MetricsFuture metricsFuture = new MetricsFuture();
    // Need to ask for the metrics to be built
    metricsFuture.buildMetrics();
    return metricsFuture;
}

private static class MetricsFuture extends AbstractFuture<List<Metrics>> {
    // Assuming the requests are asynchronous, this should be a thread-safe list
    List<Metrics> returnObj = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    void buildMetrics() {
        for(Blah blah : bleh) {
            final Request request = new Request("abc");
            externalClient.getMetricAsync(request, new AsyncHandler<request, result>() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    onError(request, e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Request request, Result result) {
                    addMetrics(new Metrics(result.getKey(), result.getValue()));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    void onError(Request request, Exception e) {
        // Is any error a total failure? This allows us to terminate waiting
        setException(e); // alternative we could remove request or keep a list of errors
        System.out.println("Error");
    }

    void addMetrics(Metrics metric) {
        returnObj.add(metric);
        // Once we have received the expected number of results we can pass that prepare that
        // as a result of this future.
        if(returnObj.size() == bleh.size()) {
            set(returnObj);
        }
    }
}
```